# Использование fd_set в методе select

Tags: c, сокеты

Мне не понятно, как пользоваться структурой fd_set вместе с select и неблокирующими сокетами для создания tcp-сервера.Ниже приведен примерный каркас того, как это всё взаимодействует. Мне не понятно как работает селект, какие есть "правила" для работы с ним, при чём тут структура с fd_set и для чего она нужна. Почему в примере две таких структуры, которые решают , когда принимать от клиента информацию, а когда можно только отправлять.

```
int ls;    // Сокет, прослушивающий соединения
int cs[N]; // Сокеты с подключенными клиентами
fd_set rfd;
fd_set wfd;
int nfds = ls;
int i;
struct timeval tv = {1, 0};
while (1) {
  FD_ZERO(&rfd);
  FD_ZERO(&wfd);
  FD_SET(ls, &rfd);
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    FD_SET(cs[i], &rfd);
    FD_SET(cs[i], &wfd);
    if (nfds < cs[i])
      nfds = cs[i];
  }
  if (select(nfds + 1, &rfd, &wfd, 0, &tv) > 0) {
    // Есть события
    if (FD_ISSET(ls, &rfd)) {
      // Есть события на прослушивающем сокете, можно вызвать accept,
      принять
      // подключение и добавить сокет подключившегося клиента в массив cs
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      if (FD_ISSET(cs[i], &rfd)) {
        // Сокет cs[i] доступен для чтения. Функция recv вернет данные,
        recvfrom - дейтаграмму
      }
      if (FD_ISSET(cs[i], &wfd)) {
        // Сокет cs[i] доступен для записи. Функция send и sendto будет
        успешно завершена
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Произошел таймаут или ошибка
  }
}
```

Comment: `select` это достаточно ущербная функция и использовать ее не стоит.

Comment: @VTT, лаба заставляет

Comment: [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) прочли?

Comment: Может poll? epoll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Мне не понятно как работает селект, какие есть "правила" для работы с ним, при чём тут структура с fd_set и для чего она нужна.

Данная функция ([select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)) позволяет процессу сообщить ядру, что нужно подождать наступления некоторых событий, и вывести процесс из состояния ожидания только после того, как наступит одно из таких событий или пройдет заданное количество времени.

Сигнатура функции:

```
int select(int nfds
    , fd_set *readfds      // Дескрипторы, готовые для чтения
    , fd_set *writefds     // Дескрипторы, готовые для записи
    , fd_set *exceptfds    // Дескрипторы, требующие обработки исключения
    , struct timeval *timeout);
```

> Почему в примере две таких структуры, которые решают , когда принимать от клиента информацию, а когда можно только отправлять.

Аргументы `readfds`, `writefds` и `exceptfds` определяют список дескрипторов, которые ядро должно проверить на возможность чтения, записи и на наличие исключений, соответственно. Список дескрипторов, как правило, это массив целых чисел, и каждое такое число рассматривается как bitset, то есть в массиве из *4* 32-разрядных чисел мы сможем хранить следующую информацию:

```
fds[0]; // биты соответствуют дескрипторам от 0  до 31
fds[1]; // биты соответствуют дескрипторам от 31 до 63
fds[2]; // биты соответствуют дескрипторам от 64 до 95
fds[3]; // биты соответствуют дескрипторам от 96 до 127
```

Реализация такого набора - тип данных `fd_set`. Вам не обязательно понимать, как он реализован, т.к. для работы с ним предоставлены следующие макросы:

```
void FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
int  FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
void FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
void FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
```

Мы размещаем в памяти набор дескрипторов и с помощью вышеуказанных макросов работаем с ним.

В процессе выполнения функция select изменяет значения, находящиеся в наборах дескрипторов. До того, как вызвать select мы указываем дескрипторы, которые нас интересуют, после ее выполнения получаем набор из дескрипторов, которые готовы.
Проверить дескриптор можно с помощью макроса FD_ISSET - если дескриптор не готов, то и соответствующий ему бит будет сброшен.

**Устанавливайте интересующие Вас биты (читать как *интересующие Вас дескрипторы*) каждый раз, когда вызываете функцию select.**

Сокет готов для чтения при следующих условиях:

1. Количество байт данных в приемном буфере сокета >= минимального количества данных ([LWM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/gtpc1/gtpc1mst86.html))
2. Закрывается соединение (получен сегмент FIN);
3. Происходит ошибка.

Сокет готов для записи при следующих условиях:

1. Количество байт данных в буфере отправки сокета >= минимального количества данных (см. SO_SNDLOWAT);
2. Соединение закрыто (получите SIGPIPE);
3. Происходит ошибка.

> select и неблокирующими сокетами

Вам нужно будет изменить логику по обработке ошибок: например, select скажет нам, что дескриптор готов для чтения, мы начинаем читать, а функция чтения возвращает ошибку `EWOULDBLOCK` - вам не нужно ее обрабатывать (имею ввиду, принимать *радикальные* меры).

Comment: Очень хорошо всё описано. Вы только не пояснили  TS простую истину, что использовать *select* (блокирующий!) с НЕблокирующими сокетами, это то же самое, что солить сахаром.

Comment: @Sergey, спасибо! Я, кажется, понимаю, о чем Вы, но все же объясните чуть-более подробно, пожалуйста.

Comment: *объясните чуть-более подробно* - сложно в двух словах. 1) Предположим, вы пишите СЕРВЕР, который обслуживает МНОГО клиентов. Сколько будет соединений в данный конкретный момент Вы не знаете. Вам надо обрабатывать запроосы от любого клиента, после того, как он принят и отправлять ответ, после того, как он готов. 2) Внутри цикла обслуживания вы принимаете соедиения. 3) Каждое установленное соедиение Вы помещаете в *fd_set*.  4) Зависаете на *select*. 5) Когда соскочили с *select* - проверяете, что произошло - какие fd_set изменились ?

Comment: Если изменился *fd_set* чтения - читаете клиентский запрос из буфера и отдаёте его на обработку. Если изменлся *fd_set* записи - проверяете, есть ли данные для передачи этому клиенту. И так в цикле. Существенно, что висите на *select* в главной нити, а обработку запросов отдаёте в дочерние, что бы они НЕ висели.

Ну и, разумеется, использовать можно только БЛОКИРУЮЩИЕ сокеты. Если сокет не блокирующий, то *select* соскочит с ожидания в тот же момент и вы ничего не поймёте.

Comment: @Sergey, я понял Вашу точку зрения. И в контексте приведенного Вами примера (а так же ТС) - я с ней согласен. Мне просто показалось, что в первом комментарии Вы хотели сказать, что так делать нельзя в принципе - а вот с этим я бы уже поспорил.

Comment: @isnullxbh, просто такой сервер называют сервер с неблокирующими сокетами и параллельным обслуживанием без многопоточности, но где здесь параллельность , это же просто очередь