# Не могу создать чат на языке си

Tags: c, сеть

Хочу сделать полноценный чат на языке си, с регистрацией и прочим. Но возникла проблема в дефиците информации в области сетей на языке си. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно обеспечить неизвестное количество клиентов соединением с другими клиентами, функция `fork` тут не подходит, но в инете нашел, что тут нужна функция `select`. Порылся я в интернете и нигде не нашел понятного объяснения этой функции, может подскажите как это реализовать, или, если не лень, опишите подробно `select`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование fd\_set в методе select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971009/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-fd-set-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-select)

Comment: @isnullxbh, я видел этот вопрос

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич, так, и ...? Вы констатируете факт или хотели что-то сказать? Извините, просто не понятно, вы не автор вопроса, просто появляетесь в комментах и говорите, что Вы видели этот вопрос - это выглядит немного странно :)

Comment: @isnullxbh, Ой:) Да это мой второй аккаунт, забываю постоянно)) Я имел ввиду что я слишком туп, чтобы понять ответ на тот вопрос.

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич, начните с ответа ниже, а где-то в середине вернитесь к вышеупомянутому ответу (если еще актуально, конечно).

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2881910/

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, 1000 страниц ради одного чата?))

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич 1000 страниц ради умения писать сетевые приложения, включая чаты.

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич, поддерживаю Сергея. Очень хорошая книга.

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич, разобрались или что-то все еще непонятно?

Comment: Спасибо за удаление второго аккаунта, в следующий раз не буду говорить что он у меня имеется, ошибку понял

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для Unix-based операционных систем актуальными являются следующие модели ввода/вывода:

- блокируемый ввод/вывод
- неблокируемый ввод/вывод
- мультиплексирование ввода/вывода
- ввод/вывод, управляемый сигналом
- асинхронный ввод/вывод

В данном случае нас интересует модель мультиплексирования ввода/вывода, которая подразумевает наличие возможности сообщить ядру, что мы хотим получить уведомления о некоторых условиях для ввода/вывода. Мультиплексирование I/O в Unix-based операционных системах обеспечивается такими функциями как [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), [poll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [epoll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) (на заметку: в macOS, например, нет функции epoll, но есть функция kqueue).

**Функция select**

Позволяет сообщить ядру, что необходимо подождать, пока не произойдет одно из некоторого множества событий, и вывести процесс из состояния ожидания только тогда, когда произойдет одно или несколько таких событий или истечет время ожидания.

Примеры событий:

- один из дескрипторов [...] готов для чтения
- один из дескрипторов [...] готов для записи
- один из дескрипторов [...] требует обработки ошибки
- истекает время ожидания получения уведомления об каком-либо из событий

Сигнатура функции select:

```
int select(int        nfds
    , fd_set         *rfds
    , fd_set         *wfds
    , fd_set         *efds
    , struct timeval *timeout
    );
```

1. `rfds` - набор дескрипторов, которые должны быть проверены на возможность чтения
2. `wfds` - набор дескрипторов, которые должны быть проверены на возможность записи
3. `efds` - набор дескрипторов, которые должны быть проверены на наличие ошибок
4. `timeout` - собственно, тайм-аут

Последний аргумент позволяет реализовать три разных модели поведения функции select:

1. Ждать вечно, для этого передаем указатель на ноль.
2. Ждать определенный промежуток времени, для этого необходимо создать и инициализировать экземпляр типа `timeval` и передать указатель на нее в функцию.
3. Ждать не более, чем необходимо для проверки дескрипторов (polling) - для этого так же необходимо создать экземпляр типа `timeval`, только вот инициализировать Вы его должны нулевыми значениями.

Про работу с дескрипторами я уже отвечал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971009/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-fd-set-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-select).

Простой пример можно найти [здесь же](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), в конце man-страницы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0, &rfds);

    /* Wait up to five seconds. */

    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

    if (retval == -1)
        perror("select()");
    else if (retval)
        printf("Data is available now.\n");
    /* FD_ISSET(0, &rfds) will be true. */
    else
        printf("No data within five seconds.\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Как только Вы введете что-то в консоли и нажмете Enter - у Вас тут же отобразится сообщение *Data is available now*. Почему это случилось: мы добавили дескриптор стандартного потока ввода данных в descriptor set, который передали функции select в качестве параметра rdfs - иными словами, мы попросили ядро сообщить нам, когда в stdin окажутся какие-нибудь данные; как только эти данные там оказались - нам пришло "уведомление". Пусть Вас не смущает, что в примере используется stdin - как и у открытого сокета, у него есть дескриптор, который мы можем использовать как уникальный идентификатор для работы с файлом.

P.S. Обратите внимание на то, как проинициализированна стуктура timeval.

**UPD.**: nfds - задает максимальное число проверяемых дескрипторов. Его значение должно быть на единицу больше максимального номера проверяемого дескриптора. В примере мы работаем с stdin, чей дескриптор равен 0. Поэтому в select была передана 1 (0 + 1 = 1).

> Но некоторые моменты остались непонятны, почему я могу ввести данные в stdin? Я же не использовал для этого никаких функций на подобии gets или scanf

Пример не подразумевает использование этих данных, но вводить Вам никто не запрещает. Даже если Вы не используете функции вроде scanf, данные с консоли попадают в stdin.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ и извиняюсь за долгий игнор. Скачал книжку "язык c++ глазами хакера" и понял более-менее как работает функция, но без вас я бы скорее всего рыдал от недостатка информации, понятной такому дурачку как я:-)

Comment: Но некоторые моменты остались непонятны, почему я могу ввести данные в stdin? Я же не использовал для этого никаких функций на подобии gets или scanf

Comment: Что вообще значит первый аргумент в функции `select`? И зачем нужно обнулять `rfds`?

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич, я бы на Вашем месте не читал такие книги (а я читал ее :) Скачайте книгу, про которую Вам сказал Сергей Горностаев (купить ее уже не получится, когда я ее искал - в магазинах ее не было) и прочтите главу про мультиплексирование I/O. После ознакомления, скорее всего, Вы не станете ее использовать, а отдадите предпочтение epoll, например. Что касается вопросов - сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: Спасибо вам:-) Возьму на заметку